# Pull Column Data with PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Okay I have been able to pull a random account and pull one account as long as I predefine it but now im curious as to how to pull a account based on the Account Number

So basicly if the account number matches pull all the data for that row.

```
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']     ['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);

  $AccountNumber = "uwoi1002"

  $query = $db->query("SELECT `content`.`ProfilePic` FROM `content`");

 while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 $Hello = $row['ProfilePic'];
 echo  '<html><img src="http://www.MYDOMAIN.COM/Content/';
 echo $Hello;
 echo '"></html>';

 }
  ?>
```

So what this is doing is returning everyones profile pics on one page Not quite what I want

I have it where in a feild on my mysql data base it has a unique Id for each account I would like it to randomly pic one of those then return all the data for that row

FirstName
LastName
Gender
City
State
FacebookUrl
BirthMonth
BirthDay
BirthYear
AccountNumber - This is the one I want to pull based on
ProfilePic
ProfilePicCaption
So basically pick a random row and pull all the data instead of displaying all the data for one column

Thank you any and all help is awesome and at least now im using secure code

Comment: If you only want record, why do you have a loop? Also, do you mean you need a `WHERE` and don't know how to bind parameters, or...?

Comment: Do you want to get the account with specified account number or just a random account?

Comment: I want to get all the data for the account based the accountnumber so basicly just look for that account number then pull all the data for that account

Let me know if this still isnt making since im sure there is a better way to describe it

Comment: so you add... `WHERE their_unique_identifier = 'the_unique_value'`

Comment: So like this ???
while ($row = WHERE their_unique_identifier  '50b05fed59e54') {

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you jsut need a `WHERE` clause...

```
// the ?, called a placeholder will have the value substituted for it
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `content`.`ProfilePic` FROM `content` WHERE id = ?");

// an array of values for the placeholders in the query
$stmt->execute(array(2));

while(false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) {
   // do stuff with data
}
```

Alternatively if you can use named placeholders which i would recommend if you have a query with lots of parameters:

```
// the :id, called a placeholder will have the value substituted for it
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `content`.`ProfilePic` FROM `content` WHERE id = :id");

// an array of values for the placeholders in the query
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => 2));
```

Comment: Maybe there was no data... You should get an error or Exception otherwise.

Comment: no there is data in there... let me look and try to find something that looks odd

Comment: I feel like this is correct but still not returning hello

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `content`.`AccountNumber` FROM `content` WHERE id = 2");
$stmt->execute(array($AccountNumber));

while(false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) {
   echo 'hello';
}

Comment: no thats not correct. The elements in the array passed to `PDOStatement::execute` are parameters for the query. So if your account number the `id` and you want the value `2` then you `SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE id = ?` and then you pass the `2` in like `$stmt->execute(array(2))` you dont manually put them in the query. Edited my answer with the example you provided.

Comment: if the `id` isnt the account number that you are querying for then youd need to add that into the mix with and `AND` clause and your second condition also using a placeholder.

Comment: No what I was trying to make clear is that the name of the colum isnt accountNumber or account it AccountNumber not sure if that makes a difference. And sorry I posted the wrong example I was just messing around with that seeing if it would work that way lol

Comment: Well if you arent apssing in a parameter as in the example you gave, then you need to pass an empty array or nothing to `PDOStatement::execute`